# Troubleshooting of updation during installation of ns2 in ubuntu

Tags: updates, ns2

Due to install the ns2 program in ubuntu, ubuntu updation is not running successfully. Error occurs like -

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: **.***.**.*** **]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: **.***.**.*** **]
```

Comment: 12.10 is *old* and no longer supported. Upgrade, if/when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Muru is right. These old repositories simply do not exist anymore and therefore your apt-get returns the 404 Not found error. You can remove these lines from your repository list, but this will not get you any updates either. Move over to 14.10 (9 months supported) or 14.04 LTS (5 years supported) or wait for 15.04 (released April 2015, also 9 months). Next LTS with 5 years support comes out in April 2016 (Version 16.04)